# drupal prevent from duplicate script / style tags

Tags: drupal, duplicates

i am building a site using Drupal 7,
when i use searching with module called search by page,
in results page i have duplicated scripts and styles tags.

is some way to prevent from this?

tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add you js and CSS using drupal_add_ms or drupal_add _css and this will take care of it for you.  Try to avoid adding script tags to your templates directly.

Also, turning on CSS and js optimization may fix the issue for you. You can do this under the performance section.

EDIT: I should note that any site wide templates should be added to your themes info file.  Any templates that should be loaded conditionally should use the functions above when needed on the page. This helps avoiding have tons of unused is loaded onto the page.